# kendo ui mobile position element at bottom

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm trying to position an element at the bottom of my mobile page using kendo ui mobile. I have a tabstrip at the bottom, and I don't want it to be footer styling, so unfortunately data-role="footer" won't cut it. I'vetried setting style="bottom:-1em;" but that doesn't work, it places the div where it was before -1em.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the bottom style to work, you should either use position: fixed or absolute. Position fixed should position it according to viewport, regardless of the element's container. However position: fixed is rather buggy on mobile platforms.

Position: absolute on the other hand will position your element according to its positioned container, so in order to use it, you can place your element in the footer. The absolute position will remove the element from the page flow, so it won't affect the positioning of the TabStrip you have there. The footer doesn't have overflow: hidden, so the element can be positioned outside of it and over the content if you want.